# How can i replace my widget controller with a groovy file?

Tags: java, groovy, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

Is it possible to replace a simple widget controller with Groovy class file controller ?

```
    <widget-definition ... id="com.mywidget">
        ...
        <controller class="MyCustomController.groovy"/>
    </widget-definition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still decalre your class, and call a groovy script that you can store in database, or in the classpaht, using **ScriptingLanguagesService** class.

Or, create a cronjob with a scripting job, then you can run the cronjob from your class that will be used as a controller.

Please refere to links below for technical details.
https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/6.6.0.0/en-US/8bec04a386691014938a9996a977d07f.html

https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/6.6.0.0/en-US/8b9d40fa86691014b471f5bf5a9715dd.html

Play with those options to find a good way that fits you, I could not find any OOTB way to do what you asked for.

Comment: First options seems to be fine.Thanks for your answer :)